# Unpacking C++ pointer/reference syntax

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, reference

Recently I had a knowledge check that included code that continues to confuse me. Here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int f1(int *a) {
    return *a + 1;
}

int *f2(int *a) {
    return a + 1;
}

int *f3(int &a) {
    return &a + 1;
}

int main() {
    int t[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
    cout << f1(f3(*f2(t)));
    return 0;
}
```

The question for the assessment was "What is the output of the program?". By compiling this I get three.

I know that this is displaying different ways by which to deal with pointers and references, but I cannot make heads or tales of the logic.

Can someone comment the different lines of this code breaking down the methods by which the reference to the `t` array/vector is being handled? In particular I do not understand how the `int *function` interacts with the result (whether it is returning a reference or a value I cannot tell). Then inside the different bodies of the functions how the dereferencing/referencing operator is being used or not being used. I am just trying to unravel the logic of it all and I keep getting twisted around the axle.

**EDIT**
With a bit of help I believe I have this one licked. Check my answer below.

Comment: Draw the array on a piece of paper. Draw arrows that point to its elements as you trace through the code.

Comment: " I do not understand how the * in "int *function" interacts with the result (whether it is returning a reference or a value I cannot tell)"  Neither, it's returning a pointer.

Comment: Why don't you write out the problem. What do you think what is happening? If you don't know about pointers and pointer dereferencing, [read this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/). We are not going to do your homework for you, as you will not learn anything. Try playing around with pointers in C++ in for instance Microsoft Visual Studio

Comment: @molbdnilo thank you, I will follow that suggestion. I might even post a breakdown in reply.

Comment: @NeilButterworth so by that logic if it tries to return a value other than a pointer it will error out, correct?

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius I will take that suggestion. Thankfully I'm just casually going through a C++ course online. Not even through a school so no homework involved!. But this problem stood out in particular and I wanted to know more about it. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Brad It should at least give a warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide and conquer:

```
int t[] = {0, 1, 2, 3}; // t is a pointer to the first element of the array
int &a(*f2(t)); // f2(t) returns a pointer, so you need to "dereferencing" using *, to get the referece to the value
int *b = f3(a); //f3(a) take an int by reference and return a pointer to an int
cout << f1(b); //f1(b) take a pointer to an int and returns an int value;
```

Also be careful with these two lines:

```
return &a + 1;
```

and

```
return *a + 1;
```

Maybe the are not doing the thing that you are thinking.

Remember that these 3 functions are just incrementing a pointer by pointer arithmetic

Comment: thank you very much for the clear explanation. I have one last question. For the function "f1". It returns the int value 3 by derefencing the t[2] element and adding one to its value, correct?

Comment: You need `int& a = *f2(t)`, otherwise the address gotten by `f3(a)` will not point into the array, and the subsequent pointer arithmetic will FAIL

Comment: @BenVoigt I see what you are saying. If it declares it is accepting a reference value of that type it will need just that as return value from `f2`.

Comment: @Brad: `f2` returns a pointer, when you apply `*` to a pointer you get a reference.  That reference can be used to initialize a reference (`int& a = `) or a copy (`int a = `) but the code in the question does `f3(*f2(t))` and Rama's rewrite is invalid because of the extra copy.

Comment: @BenVoigt good point! I edited the reference line: `int &a(*f2(t));`

Comment: @ssell So by that logic `f2(&t[0])` returns `int *t[1]`, `f3(*(int *t[1]))` returns `int *t[2]`, and `f1(int *t[2])` returns the int value of `t[2] + 1`.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah, so `f1` uses `*` to grab the reference of `int *t[2]` then adding one changes the reference to the next element of the array returning its int value.

Comment: @Brad it may be helpful to talk about the ADDRESS. Both pointers and references depend heavily on the address sorted inside, the difference is that while both pointer and references allow access to both address and value, references are focused on the value and pointers are focused on the address.

Answer (score 0):

With a great amount of help from Rama, Ben Voigt, and ssell among others. I believe I have been able to really deconstruct this problem. I hope it provides help to others.

Beginning with main ():

```
int t[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
```

An array by the name of `t` is populated with four elements (0, 1, 2, and 3). So `t[0] = 0`, `t[1] = 1`, `t[2] = 2`, and `t[3] = 3`.

```
cout << f1(f3(*f2(t)));
```

We want to print the final results of these nested functions. Their invocation order is first `f2()` which returns its value to `f3()` which returns its value to `f1()` the value of which is printed with `cout`. So the resulting value returned from `f1()` will determine our final output. The `t` array is supplied as an argument to `f2()` which without an element represents a reference to the first element of the array, essentially `&t[0]`. Now we jump to `f2()` to begin!

```
int *f2(int *a)
```

This function will return a type of pointer `int *`. It is accepting an actual argument of the same type. In this case `int *a = &t[0]`, the pointer `a` has been set to the reference of the first element of the `t` array.

```
return a + 1;
```

The variable `a` which currently holds a pointer to the address of `&t[0]` is incremented by 1, which in this case changes the pointer to the next element of the array, `&t[1]`. We now head to `f3()`

```
int *f3(int &a)
```

The the argument of this function will not accept a pointer, it needs an `int` value to perform the `&` referencing operator on. Therefore the `*` dereferencing operator is used on the value returned from `f2(t)`. Dereferencing `$t[1]` results in just the element itself `t[1]` that can be passed by reference to `f3()` via the `int &a` argument.

```
return &a + 1;
```

The reference value of `a` is incremented by one, moving the reference a single integer's worth of memory forward to the next element in the array `t[2]`, and returns the incremented reference value as a pointer. ON TO `f1()`!

```
int f1(int *a)
```

This function returns the integer that will be printed to the screen. The pointer to `t[2]` will fit nicely into the int pointer argument `int *a`.

```
return *a + 1;
```

The return statement `*` dereferences the pointer to `t[2]` acquiring its value. According to the array initialization above `t[2] = 2`, so `t[2] + 1 == 3`. The value is returned and `cout` prints `3`.

Thanks for the big help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

- `f2(t)` is `&t[0] + 1` which is `&t[1]`
- `*(&t[1])` is `t[1]`
- `f3(t[1])` is `&t[1] + 1` which is `&t[2]`
- `f1(&t[2])` is `t[2] + 1` which is `3`

Comment: I see that I need to revise my answer in explanation of dereferencing the result of `f2()`. Thanks!